# Temporary and socket files are created in home folder Linux

Tags: linux, temporary-files

I have created ~/tmp1, ~/tmp2, ~/tmp3, ~/tmp4 folders for my own use. The files placed there were not automatically generated, I created them myself or copied/moved the content there. I have used ~/tmp1 most oftenly. However, one time I found there many system generated .tmp and .sock files. I have tried deleting the whole folder, however, the folder still creates itself (ie. "~/tmp1"). Here you can see the screenshot of what I have there:

[image: wtf]

I cannot post the "tree" command output due to stack overflow length restrictions.

The question is, where do I even start to look for the problem? Sorry for so little info, please indicate what more info would you need, I will provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem actually was that in my "~/.aliases" file, which is sourced by "~/.zshrc", I had a line

```
    export TMP=/home/riddle/tmp1
```

and $TMP variable is a convention variable that actual applications will check for to determine the temp dir they should write to.